# Find files which are created a certain time after or before a particular file was created

Tags: shell, shell-script, find, date

I need a shell script which finds files which are created 1 hour before or 1 hour after a particular file (`test.txt`) was created.

If I go with `find -newer`, that means I'd have to create a temporary file, use `touch` to change the time on that 1 hour before the creation time of the `test.txt` file, and then use `-newer tempFile` to find the files which are newer than the `tempFile`, ultimately finding the files which are created 1 hour before the test.txt file. Then I have to go back through that process to find those an hour or more *older* than the file I'm interested in. That seems like a lot of extra work to go through to answer a simple question.

I also see `find -mmin`, but I worry that it's an extension to POSIX `find`.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: No common file system records the creation time of a file.  You can use the last time a file was modified, the last time it was accessed, and the last time its meta-data was modified.  There is no way to know when a file was created (unless you are using an exotic file system.)

Comment: Mac OS X records the 'birth time of an inode', which is as good as you're going to get for a 'create time'.

Comment: The options to `find`, even GNU `find`, don't make that an easy query.  Your best bet is probably to create two temporary files, touch one of them with the oldest time stamp that you want, touch the other with the newest time stamp that you want, and then use `-newer` etc.  Not neat and tidy.  I have tools that would help me, but they're homebrew and not widely available.

Comment: Probably using the inode change time is an acceptable approximation for a homework assignment, though (perhaps that's even what the professor mistakenly wants).

Comment: What tools are available? What you're doing is as simple as it gets with only POSIX tools.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken your question had `linux` tag on SO before the merge. Is GNU find available in your environment?

Comment: Yes, GNU find is available for me. Currently using Debian GNU 6.0.5. Why? Is there a difference in the various finds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another complicated option:

1. get `test.txt`'s modification time (`mtime`)
2. calculate `"before delta" = now + hour - mtime` (assuming `mtime` is in the past)
3. calculate `"after delta"  = now - hour - mtime if now - mtime > hour else 0`
4. run `find -type f -mmin -"before delta" -mmin +"after delta"`

It finds all files that are modified less than "before delta" minutes ago and greater than "after delta" minutes ago i.e., +/- hour around `test.txt`'s modification time.

It might be simpler to understand if you draw `now`, `mtime`, `"before"`, `"after"` times on a line.

`date` command allows to get `now` and `mtime`.

As a one-liner:

```
$ find -type f -newermt "$(date -r $file) -1 hour" -a \
            \! -newermt "$(date -r $file) +1 hour"
```

Comment: I see your solution, but isn't there a more 'elegent' way of doing this? 
Apparently there is a 1 line solution for this problem...

Comment: @teenOmar: I've added a one-line solution

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use `-o` as opposed to `-a` since I'm looking for files created 1 hour before **OR** 1 hour after the file creation/modification. Also is the one liner to be used in conjunction with anything else? I.e does `$file` have to be declared before somehow or can I just do `"$(date -r test.txt) -1 hour"` ?

Comment: Ok, @j-f-sebastian tried the various ways out, however the one liner isn't fool proof. Doesn't seem to work all the time, especially when i break it down into separate chunks i.e. finding the files which are created one hour after `test.txt`. Any ideas?

Comment: @teenOmar: **`-a`** is correct: the command returns files that should be *both* newer than `test.txt` modification time minus an hour *and* older than `test.txt` modification time plus an hour i.e., in +/- hour around `test.txt` time. You can use just `test.txt` instead of `$file`.

Comment: @teenOmar: It seems I've misread your question. My answer gives files *within* one hour of `test.txt`. Your question asks about files *outside* the time range (the answer could be easily modified just swap `+/-` in the conditions). To get files modified one hour after `test.txt`: `find -type f -newermt "$(date -r test.txt) +1 hour"`.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian: what I'm saying is that currently your code picks up anything that is in the timeframe of being newer than the `test.txt` file by up to 59 minutes, as the `! -newermt ...` deals with that. Your code currently only finds the files **after** the `test.txt` file, but it doesn't find the files which were created within the 1 hour tie frame before it. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @teenOmar: your sentences contradict each over. Does it only finds files newer or older than `test.txt`? Do you look at the modification times or something else? I don't know how to say it more clearly. For example, if `file=test.txt` is last modified at 7pm than *the command in the answer* should find files modified at 6:01pm, 6:30pm, 7:30pm, 7:59pm (same day) and it should *not* find files modified at 5:30pm, 5:59pm, 8:01pm, 8:30pm. In particular the command should find the file itself. It works as expected on Ubuntu

Comment: Hmmmm I see what you're saying, however in my case if I have the following files: 'testBefore.txt' with the modification time of 6pm and then 'test.txt' at 7pm and lastly 'testAfter.txt' at 8pm, your code will only bring up 'test.txt' and 'testAfter.txt', but not 'testBefore.txt'

Comment: @teenOmar: you might have noticed that I'd not used in my example times that are on the boundaries exactly. Try `testBefore.txt` with `6:01pm`, `test.txt` with 7pm, and `testAfter.txt` with `7:59pm`. You could use `-61 minutes` instead of `-1 hour` to include the boundary.

Comment: You're right, your solution works ;) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Try the following shell code:

```
file=</PATH/TO/FILE>
date=$(perl -le '$s = (stat($ARGV[0]))[9]; print $s;' "$file")
now=$(date +%s)
seconds=$((now - date))
mins=$((seconds / 60))
find . -mmin -$((mins + 60 )) -mmin +$((mins - 60)) -print
```

Comment: The `stat` call is not portable.

Comment: `date --reference` does not work? This would avoid the `stat`command.

Comment: `stat` substitued for a `perl` one-liner

Comment: `date --reference FILE '+%s'` works for me on archlinux

Comment: `date --reference FILE '+%s'` doesn't work on Solaris 11. My script is working well on this platform (bash shell).

Comment: Apparently there is a 1 line solution to this problem, not sure if that includes any perl scripting or if it's straight bash shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
d=$(TZ=UTC0 date -r test.txt +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)
```

or

```
d=$(TZ=UTC0 find test.txt -prune -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM.%.2TS\n'
```

or

```
d=$(TZ=UTC0 stat -f %Sm -t %Y%m%d%H%M.%S text.txt)
```

Depending on whether you've got access to GNU date, GNU find or BSD stat (the idea being that unfortunately, there is (reasonably) no POSIX and reliable way to get the modification time of a file)

And then:

```
TZ=XXX-1 touch -t "$d" sooner
TZ=XXX+1 touch -t "$d" later
find . -newer sooner ! -newer later
```

The `TZ=XXX<offset>` format is standard and means *defining* the "XXX" timezone as being this `<offset>` to UTC, so the "UTC" or "XXX" in the TZ variables above are arbitrary and irrelevant.

Note that none of `find -mmin`, `stat`, `find -printf`, `date +%s`, `date -r` (let alone `--reference`) are portable or POSIX.

`perl` is generally more widely available than any of those, and you can do the whole thing with perl (using `File::Find`).

`ksh93` or `zsh` (more easily) also have the ability to perform the whole task internally.

I said *reasonably* above, because it is possible to get the modification time of a file (as epoch time), provided its name is not too long and doesn't contain newline characters, POSIXly, but it's a bit convoluted:

```
{
  echo ibase=8
  printf '%s\n' test.txt |
    pax -x ustar -wd |
    dd 2> /dev/null bs=4 skip=34 count=3 |
    tr -d '\0'
  echo
} | bc
```

Converting it to a YYYYmmddHHMM.SS format in the UTC timezone POSIXly is also possible but also quite an effort (see http://stchaz.free.fr/wide_strftime.sh as an example)