# How to change last modification date and time, regardless of timezone and DST?

Tags: solaris, timezone, touch

I have two files and I need to change their last modification date: both should be midnight, one on 25th June and the other one on 25th November. Basically, this:

```
touch -cmt 201606242359.60 summer-file
touch -cmt 201611242359.60 winter-file
```

Our server timezone is "Europe/Madrid", therefore we *enjoy* daylight saving time: we are in UTC+1 during the winter and UTC+2 during the summer. Which means that if I run the above commands now, they set the *winter-file* date correctly, but *summer-file* is one hour early: 24th June 23:00. If I ran them during the summer, I guess the *summer-file* would be the one OK and the other one would be 1:00 instead of 0:00.

After [a bit of googling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184234/touch-the-file-to-future-time-stamp) and a bit more of trial and error, I came up with this:

```
TZ=ZZZ-1 touch -cmt 201606242359.60 summer-file
TZ=ZZZ-1 touch -cmt 201611242359.60 winter-file
```

Which correctly set the date of both files to 0:00 as intended. The problem is... I really don't know what I'm doing here. Changing the timezone to `ZZZ-1`, because of... magic? Or... is it -1 because we are currently in UTC+1? Next March, when we switch to DST, our server will be 2 hours ahead of UTC instead of 1. Should I use then `ZZZ-2` instead, or will `ZZZ-1` still be fine? (I'd change the server date and just try myself, but I'm not allowed to do that, it would break a few things).

If I need `ZZZ-2` during the summer... is there another expression I can set `TZ=` to instead, to make my touch work properly all around the year and for any target date? I've tried with `GMT`, `UTC` [and `UTC0`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50165/201714), none of them did work (they all set my summer-file to 1:00).

The commands are generated programmatically (in Siebel CRM), I guess I could check the current date and set `TZ=ZZZ-1` or `TZ=ZZZ-2` as needed (*if* needed), but I'd rather have only one expression.

Also, please notice our server is running Solaris 10, in case it makes any difference. It usually does...

Comment: "both should be midnight": When and where? Do you want "midnight" of your summer file be UTC+2 (=  22:00 UTC) and of your winter file be UTC+1 (= 23:00 UTC)?

Comment: You would do best with setting the correct timezone for your file(s), not relative to now. For the winter-file this would be CET (central european time), for the summer-file CEST (central european summer time), see [Time Zone Abbreviations](http://www.timetemperature.com/abbreviations/world_time_zone_abbreviations.shtml). If your "touch" were GNU touch, you could use -d instead of -t to specify the time zone as well (but I don't think this works with Solaris touch).

Comment: Thanks @ridgy. Exactly, that's what I need, "local midnight" regardless if "local" means UTC+1 or +2. And no, Solaris touch doesn't have the `-d` option :(. Not sure about what do you mean with "setting the correct timezone for your files, not relative to now"... with `TZ=CET` / `TZ=CEST`?

Comment: When I issue your original commands (without TZ=) everything works fine, so there seems to be a big difference between Solaris touch and GNU touch. So I cannot test the results, but I think the "correct timezone" would be the one valid for the respective date, so CET for the winter file and CEST for the summer. ZZZ-1 depends on now and so is a  "relative" timezone.